# Three20 competitors/alternatives

Tags: ios, three20

I see three20 a very powerful lib, spicily because Facebook and Twitter use it. I just want to know if there are any competitors/alternatives for Three20? or even simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) seems to be a project that will address some of the issues.

Comment: no, nimbus is far from three20, a lot of beautiful functions in Three20 don't exist.

Answer (score 4):

I use Three20 a lot, but I'm always in search of an alternative, because Three20 is not a lightweight framework and because importing only a few features of Three20 is not practical. But I don't know any good alternative. If you only need a few features I prefer to write my own code for it or use another library.

For some features of Three20 I know other libraries that does the same thing. It's always a better way to use small libraries, because of file size and side-effects.

1. UILabel with styled text: [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)
2. Load and cache images asynchroniously: [ImageLoader](https://github.com/yves-vogl/ImageLoader)
3. Pull to refresh on a table view: [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh)

In addition to this list you can have a look at [TapkuLibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) which adds features like CoverFlow or a CalendarView to your app.

Finally GitHub is always a good resource, when you search libraries for special features.

Answer (score 4):

Check this list of [iOS controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/controls?page=2&platform_id=ios).

You'll find over 200 open source custom controls there. I've used some of them ([star rating](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dlstarrating), [confirm button](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/maconfirmbutton)), it's lightweight and easy to embed. Check that the license suits your needs before though!

Answer (score 1):

THree20 is one of the few libs but if you look around github you can find plenty of sample ios projects with source code to learn from and adapt to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Three20 provides a lot of useful wrapper to facilitate development. It's biggest advantages and until know nothing could replace it.